Missing "Policies" in Azure AD B2C
I've been trying to learn the Azure AD B2C and have found several tutorials showing how to do it.  However, like many things in Azure they get updated and the documentation doesn't.
This this MS Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
And this article referring to "Identity Experience Framework" in overview which also does not exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
It refers to the Overview page, "Policies" which doesn't exist.  I dug around in there and can't find anything related to policy keys.  Is there an updated doc to refer to?

I think what you are looking for is in the Azure AD B2C overview. In the left menu is the "Policies" section, which includes User Flows and "Identity Experience Framework", where you can create custom policies and also you can find the "Policy Keys"


Interesting.  This didn't show when I clicked into the object.  But if I searched for the Azure AD B2C then it did.  However, when I created the first connection, it went back to the screen as if I had clicked on it (the options were missing like prior).
